# Properties remains null in my ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF application that uses MVVM. Properties are databound to my viewModel. When I press the save button, the property CompanyName of my entity Company remains always null???
I have already checked if my entity is initialized.

I have already spent some hours trying to find the cause. I taught it was something very easy to solve but I give up :-)

I have created a very simple WPF app that you can [download here](http://www.birgen.be/temp/zomergem_1.0.0.0.rar).

Regards

Comment: posting some sample code would be good to see where the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you have two instances of your view model - one which you instantiate in your views code behind, and one that is created as a resource of the view.

The bound values of the view are being written to the resource instance.  One way to fix it is to access the resource instance in your code behind, by changing the constructor code to read:

```
_viewModel = this.FindResource("ViewModel") as CompanyModel;
```

I would also seriously consider using an MVVM framework, such as [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/), [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/), or [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I will take a look at Prism.

Comment: This is an opinion, not a fact, but if you are just starting in this space, MvvmLight is a much kinder learning curve than Prism /my 2c